# How to unit test a state machine?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, state-pattern

Suppose I have an `Order` class, which can be in three different states : `CheckedState`, `PaidState` and `OrderedState`.

The state machine will be implemented using the standard State Design Pattern (Gof).

How do you usually unit test this? Do you use a fixture for each state class (`CheckStateFixture`, `PaidFixture`, ...) and one another (`OrderFixture`) for the context class? Or do you use only one fixture for the context class (`Order`) in which you'll put all the unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I preffer to keep State Infrastructure separately from entity itself. 
So you would have

- Entity class (Order)
- State infrastructure classes

For States Infrastructure I would suggest using single fixture per entity, so one `OrderStateFixture` for Order States Infrastructure will be enough.

The main tests would be the tests which ensures that Order state switches correctly:

- Ensure that initial state of an order is NotChecked
- After the successfull execution of the `Order.Paid(amount)` method Order.State switches to Paid
- If `Order.Verify()` returns true/pass without exception - Order.State becomes Checked/Verified

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I would like a clarification though, you would put those transition tests in the OrderFixture or in the OrderStateFixture ?

Comment: It depends on who is in charge to do a transition, if Order do transition itself - this would be either OrderFixture or OrderStateFixture